# View description in myUICollectionView didn't work

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm a beginner to learn ios. It's nice to be here! I have some problem using the UICollectionView.

I've add this in myUICollectionCell.m and linked the item to storyBoard

```
#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
@implementation myCollectionViewCell
@synthesize myImageView
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frameRect {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect];
    if (self) {
    myImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 60, 60)];
    myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = view2.frame.size.width/2;
    myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];     
  }
return self;
}
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "myCollectionViewCell.h"
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"cell";
  myCollectionViewCell *cell = (myCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.myImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];
  return cell;
}
```

myImageView still didn't change to circle as I described.
It can only work when I put the description into collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"cell";
  myCollectionViewCell *cell = (myCollectionViewCell*)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  cell.myImageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpg"];             
  myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = view2.frame.size.width/2;
  myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  return cell;
}
```

why is that? I'm confusing with the place where I should describe my view on my cell.

Comment: `initWithFrame:` didn't get called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using xib or storyboard, so it won't call `initWithFrame:` of `UICollectionViewCell`.

Using `awakeFromNib` instead:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //Is myImageView an outlet of storyboard? if it is you needn't realloc a UIImageView instance
    //myImageView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 60, 60)];
    myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    myImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    //[self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];
}
```